# Not able to install Win 7 on HP Notebook - 15-be001tx. Legacy mode or UEFI?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, uefi

I recently bought an HP Notebook:

- **Model Number:** 15-be001tx
- **CPU:** Intel® Core™ i5-6200U
- **RAM:** 8 GB DDR4-2133 SDRAM
- **HDD:** 1 TB 5400 RPM
- **VGA:** AMD Radeon™ R5 M430 Graphics (2 GB DDR3 dedicated)
- **OS:** FreeDOS 2.0

Now when I am trying to install *Windows 7 Ultimate (x64)* in it from a bootable USB drive, it is giving me error:

**"Windows cannot find '\ultimate.xml'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."**

[image: Error I see]

Following are some points to be noted.

1. The files were not hidden in USB. It was all unhidden. The USB drive was virus free.
2. I tried it with NTFS as well as FAT32 mode. Same error both time.
3. I enabled the Legacy Mode option from BIOS menu. The boot priority was set at highest for USB drive boot.

I am not a novice in installing OS (XP, Win7, Fedora, Ubuntu), But i have never gone up from Windows 7. Does this error has something to do with UEFI mode? Waiting for an answer.

Comment: Is it a skylake processor?

Comment: I would try wiping that USB, and putting Windows back on it and try again.

Comment: @Moab. Yes. The processor is 6200U Mobile processor. Skylake

Comment: Based on the error it seems the source .iSO you used to create the installation media was corrupt.  *You should also download a legitimate copy of the ISO for Windows 7 Ultimate, the copy you have, should not be trusted.*

Comment: Windows 7 is difficult to install on skylake processors....http://wccftech.com/intel-skylake-remove-support-usb-based-windows-7-installation-platform-specs/

Comment: But not impossible....https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/3h8vk0/build_help_installing_windows_7_on_skylake_z170/

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with EFI mode:

1. Since Windows 7 doesn't support SecureBoot, it doesn't install in UEFI mode by default, unless it has EFI bootloaders, and you restricted your BIOS to only boot in EFI mode, and you formatted your Disk as GPT (which you didn't get there yet).
2. You are using a custom bootable installation media (I can tell by looking at the picture), it's set to look for some Answer/Unattended file to sort installation I guess. That's why you get the error. Use a genuine installation media/ISO from Microsoft.